# Why does Z-axis translation (CSS transform with matrix3d) not work?

Tags: html, css, matrix, css-transforms

I have the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/trusktr/keug4tya/

On line 9, you see the DIV element (color Yellow in the output) has a Z translation of `200`. The other Green element (line 18) has a Z translation of `0`, and only the Yellow container has Z translation `200`.

`perspective:1000px` and `transform-style:preserve-3d` are applied to the root element, the `.motor-dom-scene` element.

Why doesn't the Yellow element appear in front of the green element?

Comment: Could you reduce your markup down to only the essential?

Comment: @kcdwayne Updated it.

Comment: It's minimal now. It can't get more minimal than that without changing my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that, in a scene with nested elements, the CSS property `transform-style: preserve-3d;` needs to be applied to all child-containing elements down the hierarchy, not just the root, so adding that property to the CSS solves the problem:

```
.motor-dom-node {
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: left top 0px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

Here's the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/trusktr/keug4tya/9/

Comment: And this should be the "correct answer", for the record. I.e. you should mark it correct, even though it's your own answer :)

Comment: @dudewad Thanks! I forgot since SO makes you wait before you can accept your own answer, so I left, and forgot to come back.